# Scrolling issue in jquery mobile (div scroll ) while scrolling a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile in my project . I am facing one scrolling issue.My issue is that page is scroll with fixed header (it is fine).I am using toggle class on button click(header button)  .It show some fields on click of that button .Now if i scrolling my field also scroll that is the problem.here my fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/AqbaZ/
click the fourth image .it show alert  and show search field .On scrolling the search field also scroll .how to remove that...

```
$(document).on('click', '.search_h', function() {
  //$( "#searchPopupScreen" ).popup( "open" )
    alert("Hi")
$("input[type=range]").val(60).slider("refresh");
   $(".searchContend_h").toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `<div class="searchContend_h">` into a header section [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/AqbaZ/1/)
or simply add him `position:fixed`

Comment: already try this solution .need white background ..same as previous..:(

Comment: Try this example http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/AqbaZ/2/. You just need to animate the padding.

Comment: if i have one more div slider is it work same? on fifth button i added slider i also want to stop scrolling of that

Comment: Yes, you need to perform the same calculation

Comment: When i try this .This is not a best solution for device..:(

Comment: Fixed position is not good for devices... Also fixed header and footer of jQuery mobile is not perfect and causes flickering. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html